# Joomla doesn't show menus and modules for gantry themes

Tags: frameworks, joomla, joomla1.5

I'm trying to install a theme that use Gantry framework. All the regular themes works fine, but gantry themes shows only articles (no menus, no modules, empty sidebars).

I tried to install gantry framework separately, and i also tried with bundle (theme + fw) but the result is still the same.

I am using Joomla 1.5.26 and Gantry 3.1.20 (but in Joomla admin it says v3.0.3 for Gantry ).

What can cause that? Didn't found solution in the gantry documentation.

Sorry if i am missing something obvious, i'm taking my first steps with Joomla and i need to use Gantry theme at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gantry templates use different module positions, such as "sidebar-a" instead of "right" therefore if you have a module that belongs to the "right" position", it wont show when you install the Gantry template. If you want to have the template as shown on a demo site, you should download the demo/quickstart package which contains the whole Joomla system + the template and demo content. Note that if the Gantry template not from the Rockettheme website, they may not provide the demo/quickstart package. In which case you will need to look at all the template positions and assign your current modules accordingly.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew that i miss something essential, but Joomla is entirely new CMS for me, i just didn't noticed that i have so many module position options after installing the bundle. You saved me a lot of time in trials and errors :)

Comment: You're welcome :) yeah the gantry templates are a little over the top with all those module positions lol. I think there are 78 or something silly.